# SwiftUI: Apply different animations for transitions inside ZStack

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a ZStack with multiple subviews that should have different transitions **and different animations**. Because the transition is attached to the subview this is not a problem, but the transition animation only works if the `.animation` modifier is applied to the ZStack, so I can not customize the animation per subview. Here is the example

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var shouldInsert: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            if shouldInsert {
                Color.blue.frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 0.5))
                Color.orange.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 0.5))
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.shouldInsert.toggle()
                
            }) {
                Text("Insert")
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeIn) //This should only be applied to the blue color
        .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.5))//This should only be applied to the orange color
        .padding()
    }
}
```

In the real project I have a dynamic number of subviews/color, and I have a small model for each subview color. Something similar to:

```
    @State var colors: [ColorInfo]

    struct ColorInfo {
        let id = UUID()
        let color: Color
        let animation: Animation? = nil
        let transition: AnyTransition
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try to add the `animation` modifier to the view that is supposed to be animated? You can also add a `value` parameter to the modifier which ensures that the animation is triggered only on that value change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the desired animations to the individual transitions, instead of to the ZStack:

```swift
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            if shouldInsert {
                Color.blue.frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .transition(
                        .scale(scale: 0.5)
                        .animation(.easeIn)
                    )
                Color.orange.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .transition(
                        .scale(scale: 0.5)
                        .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.5))
                    )
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.shouldInsert.toggle()

            }) {
                Text("Insert")
            }
        }
        .padding()
```